# TypeError in number of arguments passed to the _target()

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I want to run a method (speak) in a separate thread in python. Here is my code,

```
import threading

class Example:
    def instruct(self, message_type):
        instruction_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.speak, args=message_type)
        instruction_thread.start()

    def speak(self, message_type):
        if message_type == 'send':
            print('send the message')
        elif message_type == 'inbox':
            print('read the message')


e = Example()
e.instruct('send')
```

But I get following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\talkMail\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\talkMail\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: speak() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

What is the reason for this? can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

> args is the argument tuple for the target invocation. Defaults to ().

So instead of passing the argument as a string like you are doing right now, you want to pass it as a tuple like `args=(message_type,)`.
Once you do that the code works fine

```
import threading

class Example:
    def instruct(self, message_type):
        #Pass message_type as tuple
        instruction_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.speak, args=(message_type,))
        instruction_thread.start()

    def speak(self, message_type):
        if message_type == 'send':
            print('send the message')
        elif message_type == 'inbox':
            print('read the message')


e = Example()
e.instruct('send')
```

The output is

```
send the message
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. @Devesh